# How do i fix my code so that my text boxes don't come up undefined?

Tags: javascript, encoding, undefined

I am currently working on a project and I have become stuck,  after I run my program the text boxes in the app says undefined, This all occurred when I tried to add a parameter because it is required. If you see anything wrong just let me know.
Here is my code I use javascript.

```
var artNames = getColumn("Tate Museum Artworks", "Artwork Title");
var mediums = getColumn("Tate Museum Artworks", "Medium");
var years = getColumn("Tate Museum Artworks", "Year Created");
var artists = getColumn("Tate Museum Artworks", "Artist Last Name");
var websites = getColumn("Tate Museum Artworks", "Webpage");
var artNumbers = getColumn("Tate Museum Artworks", "id");

var namesFiltered = [];
var mediumsFiltered = [];
var yearsFiltered = [];
var artistsFiltered = [];
var websitesFiltered = [];
for (var i = 0; i < artNumbers.length; i++) {
  if (artNumbers[i] < 50) {
    appendItem(namesFiltered, artNames[i]);
    appendItem(mediumsFiltered, mediums[i]);
    appendItem(yearsFiltered, years[i]);
    appendItem(artistsFiltered, artists[i]);
    appendItem(websitesFiltered, websites[i]);
  }
}
updateScreen();
function updateScreen() {
  var index = randomNumber(0, namesFiltered.length - 1);
  setText("artName", namesFiltered[index]);
  setText("medium", mediumsFiltered[index]);
  setText("yearCreated", yearsFiltered[index]);
  setText("artist", artistsFiltered[index]);
  setText("website", websitesFiltered[index]);
}
onEvent("randomizeButton", "click", function( ) {
  updateScreen();
});
```

Comment: Nothing obvious is jumping out, maybe check that your helper functions are working correctly (`getColumn`, `appendItem`, `randomNumber`, `setText`)?

Comment: Thank you for your advice, unfortunately i have done so and nothing has changed.